# Python ctypes. Показать открыте приложения из панели задач (taskbar)

Tags: python, ctypes

Каким образом с помощью **Python** можно вывести все имена открытых приложений, но только из панели задач (**taskbar**)?

Пробовал искать ответы, но там показывали лишь примеры, где выводят все процессы из **tasklist**.

Comment: Вы хотите получить [список окошек в Винде как по Alt+Tab клавишам показывается](http://stackoverflow.com/q/210504/4279)?

Comment: @jfs проще говоря, хочу сделать док с открытыми приложениями.